# PHP: Will cURL finish in the background, or block all further script execution?

Tags: php, curl

I'm building an app that at one point curls some contents from an external URL. So far, this has always finished quite quickly/instantly. However, I am unsure as to what would happen if the external server took a long time to respond. Would PHP wait with the execution of the following code until cURL is finished?

I can not really test it because I don't know how to "simulate" a slower response. I hope this pseudo-code makes my question clear:

```
$ch = curl_init( $some_remote_url );
$fp = fopen( $some_local_file, 'wb' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_exec( $ch ); // Let's say this takes 20 seconds until the other server responds
curl_close( $ch );
fclose( $fp );
redirect( $some_other_url ); // Will this be executed instantly or only after 20 seconds?
```

The reason why I am wondering about this is that I would not want my user to look at a "loading" page for 20 seconds in case the remote server was responding slowly, so I would probably have to move the whole process to a cron job. The user doesn't need the result of the curling instantly, so it doesn't matter to him when the process is finished.

Comment: +1 nice question ... definitely after 20sec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curl will block execution. If you want to download the file in background (asynchronously), either use a cron scheduled task, or exec a command like this:

```
system("wget URL &");
```

Comment: As far as I know, using system() or exec() doesn't behave different from synchronous tasks like regular cURL, but passthru() does. 
Unfortunately all of these three functions are disabled on most hosted servers, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that would stop the script execution, but you could create a script which directly renders output to the remote computer and then starts via AJAX the other script to perform the cURL action you want. At the end it would return a response and your JS script would then do the redirect, or whatelse you want.

Of course this would only work by users who have JS enabled, but just to say: Everyone who doesn't have JS enabled in his browser can't browse in the web normally.